# Recursive search for files in root directory and subfolders

Tags: c#

I need to make a recursive search on a root folder with a few subdirectories, but i can't figure out, how to make rootDirectory string search without any certain folder. That i would be able to execute the file without any certain root folder say like C:\folder\file. What i need is more like RandomDirectory:\randomsubfolder\filewithout a certain extension.

```
string rootDirectory = "";
    string extension = "";


    List<string> files = GetFilesRecursively (rootDirectory, extension);

    Console.WriteLine ("Got {0} files of extension {1} in directory {2}", files.Count, extension, rootDirectory);
    foreach (string file in files) {
        Console.WriteLine (file);
    }
}





static List<string> GetFilesRecursively (string rootDirectory, string extension) {

    if (!Directory.Exists (rootDirectory)) {

        return new List<string> ();
    }
    Console.WriteLine ("Currently in directory {0}", rootDirectory);


    List<string> opList = new List<string> ();


    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles (rootDirectory, "" + extension);


    opList.AddRange (allFiles);


    string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories (rootDirectory);


    foreach (string subDir in subDirectories) {

        List<string> subDirFileList = GetFilesRecursively (subDir, extension);

        opList.AddRange (subDirFileList);
    }
```

Comment: Directory.GetFiles has a "recursive" flag on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
string [] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```