# find the installation path (with exe file there but not currently running) in win 7 from C# VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

From C# VS2013, I would like to get the whole path of an application that has been indtalled on win 7.

The post with 7 methods at:

```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path
```

**cannot help me because I do Not need the path of the current running application.**

I need the path of an application that has been installed (but **currently not running**).

I have tried

```
  string [] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

at

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736343/recursive-search-for-files-in-root-directory-and-subfolders
```

But got:

```
 Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\MSSomeApp\DATA' is denied.
```

My C# code:

```
 FileInfo executableFileInfo = new FileInfo("MyApplication.exe"); // It has been installed on win 7.
 string executableDirectoryName = executableFileInfo.DirectoryName;
```

This just returned my current VS2013 working directory.  But, actually, "MyApplication.exe" was installed at C:\MyPath.

I need to get the full file path C:\MyPath\, where all libs and exe files (of MyApplication) are there.

Any suggestions ? thanks

Comment: what is the program input? a shortcut link? of course it can't be the path of exe itself

Comment: please see my update. thansk

Comment: i'm confuse - the other question you linked seems to be a dupicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive search for files in root directory and subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736343/recursive-search-for-files-in-root-directory-and-subfolders)

Comment: I have tried the method in the link, but they just returned the current working dir.

Comment: @Lily did you try my code?

Answer (score 0):

Well You can use something like:

```
    string[] paths = 
    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles,
 "MyApplication.exe", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will look the Program Files Folder and all its Sub Folders for the file named MyApplication.exe and will return the full path of all of matches

Comment: @Lily well your program needs to have Administrator privilege to access the files in the "Program Files" folder. then the "Access Denied" error should be resolved.

Comment: The program will be run by any users, who may not have adm right on a computer.

Comment: well that can be problem. that is exactly why the admin privilege is needed. because not everybody should access the files. without admin access I don't think this will be possible.